# Evaluating summation involving binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, summation-method

> I need to evaluate
> $$\fbox{$\dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^r{{n \choose k } \cdot {{n-2k} \choose {r-k}}}}{\sum_{k=r}^{n}{{n \choose k} \cdot {2k \choose 2r} \cdot \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-k} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2k-2r}}}$}$$

**$\underline{\text{My attempt}}$**
$\require{cancel}$

I expanded the binomial coefficients in denominator as $$\dfrac{n! \cdot (2k)!}{k!(n-k)! \cdot (2r)!(2k-2r)!}$$ and took 2 outside the factorial terms which resulted in $$\dfrac{n! \cdot \cancel{2^{k}} \cdot k!}{k!(n-k)! \cdot \cancel{2^{r}} \cdot r! \cdot \cancel{2^{k-r}} \cdot (k-r)!}$$
How to proceed further?

Edit: I realised the error in my approach. Please ignore it and suggest another approach.

Comment: How is $2k!=2^kk!~~$?

Comment: Sry that was an error in formatting from my side, I corrected it now

Comment: Can you explain how $n!\cdot (2k)!$ became $n!\cdot 2^k\cdot k!~$?

Comment: Sorry again, I made a grave error writing that. I thought each term of the factorial will have a 2 as factor but Im wrong.